# Makefile usage of function with conditional

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-make, gnu

I've some commands in my gnu make file which is returning true or false

**Commands like**

```
apps := $(shell zmr build app)
...more code
service := $(shell zmr build service)
...
target := $(shell zmr build target)
```

Now I want to enhance those command to return also boolean for true of false

```
apps,isValid := $(shell zmr build app)
...
service,isValid := $(shell zmr build service)
...
target,isValid := $(shell zmr build target)
```

and when if `isValie` equal to false use **exit** in the make?

I try to read about the functions like 
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html#Conditional-Functions

or 
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function

but not sure if this is right way...any example how to handle it properly will really help me , Im a bit lost with the options

I've tried the following answer without success, any idea how I can make it work inside `makefile`?

**update -**

I want to use a function in my GNU MAKE which get `true` or `false` from c`ommand` , if get `false` it will `exit` the make process (i..e not proceed with the next command, if true proceed with the process) how it can be done **simply** and strait forward

Comment: Can you sketch the output of your `zmr` command? Is it a string with separation characters?

Answer (score 2):

> I've some commands in my gnu make file which is returning true or false
>
> ```
> apps := $(shell zmr build app)
> ```
>
> Now I want to enhance those command to return also boolean for true of false
>
> ```
> apps,isValid := $(shell zmr build app)
> ```
>
> when if `isValid` equal to false use exit in the make

Assuming your `zmr build ...`  commands outputs `true` or `false`, you can exit `make` with

```
ifeq (${apps,isValid},false)
$(error app not valid)
endif
```

`make` does not know about datatypes so `true` and `false` are just strings for it.

I do not know the semantic of your `zmr build` but it sounds like it would do some expensive things... The `$(shell ...)` operation is usually only intended for short running commands without side effects.  It might be better to put the `isValid` stuff into a target

```
apps,isValid:
    zmr build app
```

`make` will fail automatically when this command fails.

Comment: HI, what is `$(error app not valid)` I just want to exit in case `isValid` is `false`

Comment: thanks I try the first option without success  ...any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, as a matter of style, I would strive not to use `$(shell …)` and use recipes wherever possible.

Having said that,
it is possible to do what you ask.
I will just assume the last word is the status.

```
output := $(shell zmr build app && echo t || echo f)
```

Here `t` is appended to the output of `zmr` if the command succeeded.
Otherwise `f` is appended.
Now we just strip off the last word to separate the status from the command output.

```
retcode := $(lastword ${output})
apps := $(words 2,$(words ${output}),x ${output})

$(if $(filter f,${retcode}),$(error apps failed))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your needs is already quite too advanced to be managed only in a make file.

You may consider using a tool like autoconf (See. https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) which will allow you to perfectly reach your needs, with a result more legible.

Let me know if you need help for that.